# Bluetooth keyboard not responding to UIPanGestureRecognizer on Apple TV

Tags: tvos, uipangesturerecognizer, apple-tv, bluetooth-keyboard

I am getting some issue with using a bluetooth keyboard to UIPanGestureRecognizer which is used for scrolling a textview. Do I need a different recognizer to detect up and down arrows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to scroll a text view, the text view already has a built-in gesture that listens for keyboard events (or any other `UIPress` event), you just need to enable it.

```
textView.directionalPressGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

Same thing for using touches to scroll it: the text view's built-in pan gesture can recognize those touches, but it doesn't by default on tvOS. That's because the normal use-case on TV is for touches to move focus, not scroll the scroll view. You can get the pan gesture to listen to touches by changing it's `allowedTouchTypes` like so:

```
textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[ @(UITouchTypeIndirect) ];
```

Comment: thanks, this lead me to this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19184 which solved my problem by adding the directionalPressGestureRecognizer to the parent view.